# Android - JUnit how to mock a parent activity class?

Tags: android, junit, mocking

I have to do android JUnit test for a parent activity class, which is not declared in AndroidManifest.xml. I'm trying to Mock the class, but I am new to Java. Please give a example to do that.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

For reference i think this tutorial will help you 
http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/activity_test.html

Comment: Could you please give me some details? Thank you.